# Redirect pagination to base Url in website Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can I display the URLs on my site in a cleaner fashion, example:

Change

**example.com/item/page-1.html**

to

**example.com/item/**

Comment: In WordPress, posts automatically manage their old and new permalinks change. In case your are facing the broken link issue, use some plugin to achieve this, are you sure that you want to do it through .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update permalinks to not include index.php then add a .htaccess file to the wordpress folder and add the following content to it:

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Then go to the Wordpress Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks > and change it to "post name" and save changes.